# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (193)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Pls I need help.
I am learning Dot Netcore and I want to use VS Code but when I try to run or build my app but it keeps failing, I was able to run it on Microsoft Visual Studio but it is pretty large for my PC and I'd rather use VS Code should in case I want to use a MacBook in the future

Error Message System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (193)

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Download correct runtime version.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: error message: `the specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform` so I think you need to make sure if the application can run well via Visual studio in the same computer. Then make sure you've installed correct runtime version like @jdweng said. and finally delete the `bin` and `obj` folder then rebuild and run the app.

Comment: Alright thank you so much, let me try that

Comment: @toyotaSupra I have done that